# How to add loop timer in Java?

Tags: java, loops, timer

How to loop this timer? I want to print every 1 second.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer = new Timer(false);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         i--;
         System.out.println("Java " + i);
      }
   }, 0, 1000);
}
```

Comment: what is your current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really what you want, change

```
}, 0, 1000);
```

to

```
}, 0, i * 1000);
```

And put `i = 0` to `i = 1`, and `11` not `10` or use `<=`

It will create and schedule a new TimerTask 10 times

Comment: @YoavLevavi 1000 ms = 1 sec; 1 minute = 1000 * 60; 4 minutes = (1000 * 60) * 4. Instead of use timers to wait, use Thread.sleep

Comment: But it makes my program freeze

Comment: It will pause the current thread, but if you need to execute a task after X time maybe an ExecutorService could help you more since, if one task thrown an exception, it will be handled correctly while TimerTask will just close everything. But this depends on your case.

Answer (score 0):

Good way is to create your own TimerTask class.

In your Main class, you have this main method :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(10), 1000, 1000);
    }
```

And then you only need create your own TimerTask class

import java.util.TimerTask;

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private int i2;
    public MyTimerTask(int i2){
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("heej: " + i2);
    }    
}
```

This is outputing `heej: 10` every second.

---

With your own class, you can control what is happeing there like this :

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private int i2;
    private int count = 0;

    public MyTimerTask(int i2){
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("heej: " + i2);
        if (count > 10){
            this.cancel();            
        }
    }    
}
```